# Investigating Apple Motion alternatives

Tags: software-recommendation, imovie

I'm using iMovie, but i'm looking to replace the cheesy standard leaders.

I've read that you can use Apple Motion as a standalone tool to generate leaders and tranparent animations, export them to 4444 format and include them in iMovie.

I realize some functionality is lost without final cut pro but i think i do not (yet) need FXP (plus, i'm saving for a rMBP)

Are there any alternative apps that i'm overlooking for creating custom leaders/trailers before i shell out $50 ?

Comment: There is no respond to your question since it is to vague and it will generate opinions and discussions and we normally do not handle commercial questions. So consider revising it.

Comment: I thought it was ok, because i see a tag on software recommendations and quite a lot of questions from people asking for alternatives. You have a suggestion how i can improve my question?

Comment: I will be proven wrong by someone who will answer your question :)

Comment: I think this is a perfectly legitimate question. It is objective, and not subjective...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [a list of alternatives to Apple Motion](http://alternativeto.net/software/apple-motion/?platform=mac). It seems to me that most of the alternatives are 3D animation/modeling.

[Adobe After Effects](http://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects.edu.html) ($20/month, or $699)

> Adobe After Effects is a digital motion graphics, visual effects and compositing software package published by Adobe Systems, used in the post-production process of filmmaking and television production.

After Effects is your best alternative to Motion, in my opinion. However, it costs a lot more than Motion. Just stick with the $50 Apple Motion and you'll be fine. After Effects has great motion graphics, but there's also a whole lot more to After Effects than just motion graphics.

Comment: Wow. $699, If I had that money for my hobbies i'd buy a better camera! But seriously, thanks for the link to the list of alternatives.

Comment: Trust me, it's worth it. :) But a better camera is good too...

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!